# Can I remove the bottom wall plate once a new header beam is installed?

Tags: load-bearing, remodeling

I removed a section of load bearing wall in my house and installed a new header in the opening. The 2x4 at the bottom of the wall was not removed and sticks up above the surrounding flooring (~3/4" on one side and ~1/4" on the other).

The guys refinishing the floors want to remove the 2x4 so they can gradually build up between the two floor levels.
Does this sound safe?

The house is one storey built over a crawlspace, and the jack/king studs for the new opening do not sit directly over a floor joist.

Comment: You  may want to  add supports at jacks.  A post , blocking or joist. If in middle of a bay is not carrying well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's no wall there need be no plate. It should remain under any trimmer studs supporting the header, of course. Cutting it out flush with the rough opening is standard practice.